# Unable to enter for loop in Assembly due to possible improper compare

Tags: loops, for-loop, assembly, x86

I am trying to write code in assembly that will print out the proper sequence until the entered iteration is reached. I am unable to enter the for loop, I am unsure why, however, it may be due to improper use with the `cmp <dst>, <src>` call - I don't think that is why but it may be.

My data section looks like the following:

```
.data
    stmt1 db "Nathanial Mendes", 0Ah, 0

    prompt1 db "Enter maximum sequence count: ", 0
    fmt db "%d", 0

    sum db "Fib(%d) = %d", 0

    seq dd 0
```

This is what my code section looks like

```
.code 
    main PROC c
    push offset stmt1
    call printf

    ;Prompt for first int
    push offset prompt1
    call printf
    add esp, 4

    push offset seq
    push offset fmt
    call scanf
    add esp, 8

    ;Set up loop vars
    mov eax, 0 ; set i = 0
    mov ebx, 0
    mov ecx, 0
    mov edx, 0

;#############################
    beginloop:
    cmp eax, seq ; comparing the counter (eax) to the max iteration (seq) 
    jle endloop ; if it is false jump to the end of the loop

;#######
    ;code for Fib here

    ;print statement (prints out the current Fib, looks like Fib(iteration) = Fib_sum
    push eax
    push ebx
    push offset sum
    call printf
    add esp, 8

    ;next term calculations for the fib seq.
    add ecx, edx
    mov ebx, ecx
    mov ecx, edx
    mov edx, ebx
;#######
    ; set up next iteration of for-loop

    add eax, 1 ; add one to the iterator 
    jmp beginloop
;#######
    ;when the for loop is false
    endloop:

    ;Print (final) result
    push eax
    push ebx
    push offset sum
    call printf
    add esp, 8

;##########################################

    INVOKE ExitProcess,0
    main endp
end
```

Why it is that my for-loop never goes past the compare statement and goes directly to the endloop call?

Comment: Looks like it should enter once, but the rest of the code is wrong. `add esp, 8` should be `12` because you passed 3 arguments. Also `printf` is allowed to change `eax`, `ecx` and `edx` so all your locals will be overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

`cmp eax, seq` / `jle endloop` is `if(i<=seq) break` with `i=0`.  So for non-negative `seq`, you never enter the loop.

You want the opposite break condition.  Or put this loop condition at the *bottom* of your loop like an normal asm loop with the conditional branch at the bottom.  ([Why are loops always compiled into "do...while" style (tail jump)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47783926/why-are-loops-always-compiled-into-do-while-style-tail-jump))

As Jester commented, your code has other bugs, but that's the answer to this one.  (I think Jester is counting it as "entering the loop" once when execution passes the `beginloop:` label and reaches your `if() break` at the top of the loop body.)

This looks like MASM syntax so `seq` without `[]` is still a memory operand, not comparing against the address as an immediate.  I'd generally recommend using `[]` around memory operands in general.